# How to set values in a form automatically with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a lot of requests and **want to see only the status code**, there are areas that require to be authenticated to access which want to check. 
This **isn't a test end-to -end**, would not be useful to use the `Zombie.js` or `Nightwatch.js`.

Is there any possibility to fill the login form and making requests go after?

Comment: So, you want to test you authentication logic against all your routes using an series of automated requests whose authentication values are derived from a login form?

Comment: I wish to make a request in `/upload` and verify that the return 200 if it isn't authenticated will be redirected.

Comment: You could do this with an external unit test. Essentially run two requests against your dev server instance. One with a valid authentication payload (e.g. a test account) and one without a authentication payload.
To extract status codes from node http requests see:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen Supertest?

```
npm install supertest --save-dev
```

You can use this to simulate request and check execution or status code.

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  res.send(200, { name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '20')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res){
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

With Mocha:

```
describe('GET /users', function(){
  it('respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  })
})
```